How can I find the distance between planet and black hole?
With the movie Interstellar  how I can find time dilation of the Miller's planet? Do I need find the distance between the planet and the black hole? Then I can find the time dilation?
If not, please give me some ideas about finding time dilation of the Miller's planet then compare them with the time outside the gravitational field of the black hole effect.

I think that in the movie they mention that 1 hour in the planet corresponds to 7 years on earth. You can make your calculations with that.

This question was already answered at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/557210/24093
